# Как найти сумму массива на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, pascal

не могу правильно написать программу

```
var
i:integer;
x:array[1..10] of integer;
 begin
 for i:=1 to 10 do
 begin
  x[i]:=trunc(201*random-100);
  end;

 for i:=1 to 10 do
  begin
  write(' ', x[i]);
  write;
  end;
  asm
    mov bx, offset x
    mov ax, [bx]
  @1
  add bx, ax
  loop @1
  mov ax, bx
  mov sum, ax
  end;
  end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед loop (точнее, перед меткой начала) нужно поместить в cx количество шагов

Если в bx поместили адрес массива, то с помощью [bx] получают данные по текущему адресу. Отмечу, что регистр bx использован зря, можно обойтись dx. (иначе bx нужно сохранять и восстанавливать)

На каждом шаге bx нужно увеличивать на 2

Как инициализировать регистр для суммирования и проводить в нем суммирование на каждом шаге цикла - должно быть очевидной из обычной программистской логики.

Проверил в Delphi с edx вместо dx (поскольку 32-разрядная система)

```
asm
    mov dx, offset x
    xor ax, ax 
    mov cx, 10
@@1:
    add ax, [dx]    
    add dx, 2
    loop @@1

    mov sum, ax
end
```

Ещё вариант (не проверял)

```
asm
   lds si, x    {адрес массива}
   xor dx, dx 
   mov cx, 10
@@1:
   lodsw   {загрузить слово в ax из [si]}
   add dx, ax    
   loop @@1

   mov sum, dx
end
```

Comment: Можете показать, как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Вот прямо ничего-ничего из сказанного не понятно?

Comment: Частично понятно

Comment: Подскажите, какую литературу можно почитать, чтобы понять ассемблер

Comment: Да любой учебник для введения в основы. Вряд ли Вам нужно глубоко вдаваться.

Comment: Вот хоть [подобный курс](http://natalia.appmat.ru/c&c++/assembler.html)

Comment: в программе он выдает ошибку
'var
i:integer;
x:array[1..10] of integer;
 begin
 for i:=1 to 10 do
 begin
  x[i]:=trunc(201*random-100);
  end;

 for i:=1 to 10 do
  begin
  write(' ', x[i]);
  write;
  end;
asm
    mov dx, offset x
    xor ax, ax 
    mov cx, 10
@@1:
    add ax, [dx]    
    add dx, 2
    loop @@1

    mov sum, ax
end;
  end.'

Comment: Какой компилятор? Какую ошибку? Где и как sum объявлено?

Comment: Где-то не правильно написала

Comment: О, это, конечно, сильно поможет понять, что за ошибка ;)

Comment: ошибка в комбинации в [dx] и не знаю как обозначить sum

Comment: попробуйте `add ax, word ptr [dx]   и  sum:integer;`

Comment: ошибочное в регистрах

Comment: У меня работает, считает верно. Другой компилятор может не весь синтаксис поддерживать. Читайте, что там для вашего в asm разрешено. Если это TP, то в хелпе должно быть.

Comment: можете сделать 3 примера и отправить фото?

Comment: Мадемуазель, ну зачем Вам моё фото? ;-)  А если серьёзно - то читайте описание синтаксиса встроенного ассемблера TP.

Comment: не ваше фото, а ассемблера

Comment: Да я догадался. Информация Вам дана, работайте сами.

Comment: спасибо за помощь